# Image.Save does not save image data to file

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, gdi+, system.drawing

I have working Windows Form application that gets a jpeg image from and website and displays it in an Image control.  However, when I attempt to save the image to the file system using the Image.Save function, it creates the file but leaves it empty.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong...

In the following, DownloadData() successfully retrieves a byte array containing the image.

```
byte[] imageData = DownloadData(); 
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(imageData);
Image img = Image.FromStream(stream);
stream.Close();
picMain.Image = img;
string fname = @"C:\Users\mikec1\Pictures\Construction\Construction_" + Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "_" + Now.ToString("HHmmss") + ".jpg";
picMain.Image.Save(fname, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

I get the same result if I execute the Save from the img object.

In fact, the application terminates upon execution of the last line, without apparently throwing an exception.

Comment: If you leave out the file saving code, does the picture display properly via the line `picMain.Image = img;`?

Comment: Yes, it does do that properly at least.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that an `Image` instantiated using `FromStream` requires the stream to remain open for the lifetime of the `Image`. Get rid of `stream.Close()` and it should be fine. See [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93z9ee4x(v=vs.110).aspx) for details.

Comment: Nice answer, Simon!  Works like a charm!

Answer (score 3):

I tried your code and it threw an `ExternalException`, saying `A generic error occurred in GDI+`, without any `InnerException`, also creating an empty file. Omitting that line made the image show up on the form just fine. Changing .NET versions didn't seem to have any impact.

While <s>I'm not sure why that happens</s> see [Simon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35143848/4037348), you can simply avoid this problem entirely by using

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(fname, imageData);
```

instead of

```
picMain.Image.Save(fname, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

It should use less overhead also, since `Image.Save` has to deal with image formats first before saving, and you already have your byte array right there.

Comment: Good answer, works just as good as the one @SimonMcKenzie gave!  And I see you are Lithuanian!  Nice!  My late wife's parents were both born in Klaipeda, when it was part of Germany long time ago!  Of course, they called it Memel, but no matter.